# Finding area of the triangle with vertices on a quarter circle

Tags: geometry

[image]

How to find area of Blue shaded region if it is given that **AQ=2** and **BP=4**?

Comment: Is $ARB$ assumed to be a quarter circle?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @kccu Though is not given in the question that it is a quarter circle but YOu can assume it to be

Comment: @B.Núñez I tried solving it using similarity. There are 3 triangles in the figure and all of them are similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r$ be the radius of the circle.

We can apply the Pythagorean theorem to triangle $OQR$. Leg $OQ$ has length $r-2$, leg $QR$ has length $r-4$, and hypotenuse $OR$ has length $r$, so:
$$(r-2)^2+(r-4)^2=r^2$$
from which we obtain $r=2$ or $r=10$. We can rule out $r=2$ based on the diagram, hence $r=10$.

Now assuming $O=(0,0)$, you can find coordinates for all of the points and calculate the area of the shaded triangle.

Answer (score 1):

As @kccu showed, it is easy to find that $r=10$.

Next, the lengths of the triangle's sides are:

$a = \sqrt{10^2 + 10^2} = \sqrt{200}$

$b = \sqrt{4^2 + (10-2)^2} = \sqrt{80}$

$c = \sqrt{2^2 + (10-4)^2} = \sqrt{40}$

To find the triangle's area, use [Heron's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SSSTheorem.html) for a SSS (side-side-side) triangle:

$$A = \sqrt{s (s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$$

where $s = \frac{a + b + c}{2}$ to find $A = 20$.